# Chrome: Text container not 100% height

Tags: css, google-chrome, html

im having problems with having 100% height on a child container on Google Chromem, on Firefox is working excellent.

Here is the link:

```
http://linco.com.py/beta/multiplaza/cartelera.php
```

The main container:

```
position: relative;
width: 23%;
height: 0px;
padding-bottom: 30%;
margin-left: 1.5%;
margin-top: 20px;
float: left;
```

The child container:

```
z-index: 2;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
display: table;
cursor: default;
```

What im doing wrong? Thanks !

Comment: It's because of `display: table`. If you change it to default or `block`, it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is remove the line `display:table` and it will work.

Comment: Thanks, but i need the text always vertically aligned.